# Certificates and keystores

Tags: android, ios, deployment, google-play, app-store-connect

Let's say I hire a contractor to develop an app for me in both Android and iOS.  The contractor does the coding on his own computer and pushes the final products to both iTunes and Google Play. All is well.

Now two months later, the contractor wins the lottery and buys a small island off in Africa and moves there with no internet connection.  So I hire another contractor and give him/her the username and password to connect to itunes and google play console account.

Can the new contractor release updates by having just the code and not any other vars relating to the itunes and google play account?  In other words, are we still dependent on the old -- unreachable -- contractor for things like certificates and keystores files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends.. are you going to rotate your keys or certificates? Are you going to change your password to the account? I mean.. you SHOULD change it when changing contractors.. Secondly you should revoke certificates and create new ones with the new contractor.. then continue from there. As long as the Apple account is yours, there is no problem.. ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the platform:

**Apple/iOS:** Any other developer with access to your developer account can update the app. All required certificates, profiles and keys can get re-created by the new developer. You can also always revoke any old / existing certificates and profiles. The new developer just needs access to your account and to re-use the bundle ID of the app. (Which can be found over at App Store Connect)

**Google/Android:** The Google Play store works a little bit different. The new developer needs to re-use the existing package name (="bundle ID"), but also needs to sign the APK with the exact same keystore as the previous app. If you sign it with a different keystore, Google Play Dev Console will give you a warning. There is the option though to reset the keystore and provide a new one, but you need to manually contact support: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en -> Scroll down to *Lost or compromised upload key?*